# Master and slave design pattern work with transaction

Tags: php

```
<?php

class Database()
{
    public function __conscruct()
    {
        $dsnMaster = 'mysql:host=' . $config['host']['master'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'] . ';charset=utf8';
        $this->dbhMaster = new PDO($dsnMaster, $config['username'], $config['password'], $options);
        $dsnSlave = 'mysql:host=' . $config['host']['slave'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'] . ';charset=utf8';
        $this->dbhSlave = new PDO($dsnSlave, $config['username'], $config['password'], $options);
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        if (preg_match('/^select /i', $query) > 0) {
            $this->dbh = $this->dbhMaster;
        } else {
            $this->dbh = $this->dbhSlave;
        }

        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function beginTransaction()
    {
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }
}

$db = new Database;

try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->query('SELECT * FROM `tables`');
    $db->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // rollback here
}
```

This is how I design my pdo function with master and slave connection configs, I check query strings to use `SELECT` to master and other actions to slave, but the transaction will be failed because I didn't declare `$this->dbh` in the `__construct`, how to fix that?

Comment: In the `__contruct()` I cannot see a declaration of `$config` and `$options`. Where are these coming from?

Comment: Because I can only detect `SELECT` or `INSERT` behavior when user pass query string, therefore I define use `master` or `slave` connection at that time.

Comment: No, what I mean is that these variables are not declared anywhere... They shouldn't hold any data, but you are still using them to setup the connections. As a result, these connections won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding the line:-

```
$this->dbh = $this->dbhMaster
```

in the `_construct` function

Comment: I need to know the sql command to decide what connection should be used.

Answer (score -1):

You could use like below

```
public function query($query)
    {
        if (strpos($query,'select') == 0) {
            $this->dbh = $this->dbhMaster;
        } else {
            $this->dbh = $this->dbhSlave;
        }

        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }
```

Comment: This is not the issue.